# Vertically aligning validation summary text with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using some CSS classes to manipulate my validation summary. Currently, I only show the first error. I wish to align this error inside its div. However my vertical-align properties seem to be having no effect. I can see that they are applied when I inspect the element with firebug in Firefox, yet they don't render as vertically aligned (they sit at the top). The other elements of the classes render correctly.

My div

```
<div style ="float: left; max-width: 200px; height: 75px; vertical-align:middle">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
</div>
```

My CSS classes

```
.validation-summary-errors li {
color: #b94a48;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.validation-summary-errors ul li:nth-child(n+2) {
display: none;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ejZz/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vertical-align only apply to cell elements such as `<td>` or elements that have the css rule `display:table-cell`

See this example : http://jsfiddle.net/V9by8/

You should provide a jsfiddle for your problem, I could help you center it

**UPDATE**

Updataed with your code http://jsfiddle.net/9ejZz/6/

Comment: See my update for the jsfiddle. I attempted to emulate what you have in your fiddle but it doesn't seem to be working. I think it might be due to the fact that when the validation summary renders, each element in in an <li> tag

Answer (score 0):

Six methods for centering something vertically. Pick your poison. This question seriously comes up once a week...

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Line-height

```
<div id="parent">
    <img src="image.png" alt="" />
</div>

#parent {
    line-height: 200px;
}

#parent img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Table

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {display: table;}

#child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Negative Margins

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {position: relative;}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
}
```

Stretching

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {position: relative;}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Equal Padding

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {
    padding: 5% 0;
}

#child {
    padding: 10% 0;
}
```

Floater Div

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="floater"></div>
    <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>

#parent {height: 250px;}

#floater {
    float: left;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}

#child {
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
}
```